# Why am I unable to rollback my migrations?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, next.js, yarnpkg, knex.js

After my tech lead implemented a new role permissions system in our application, I've been unable to clear the database via rolling back migrations. The command I usually run is `knex --env local migrate:rollback --all`. It seems as though the new migration file (*i.e.*, 12345_updatePermissions.js) my tech lead created is what's causing the issue, since in my terminal I get returned the following error:

```
migration file "12345_updatePermissions.js" failed
migration failed with error: alter table "User" alter column "role" type text check ("role" in ('Admin', 'SuperUser', 'User')) using ("role"::text check ("role" in ('Admin', 'SuperUser', 'User'))) - syntax error at or near "check"
error: alter table "User" alter column role" type text check ("role" in ('Admin', 'SuperUser', 'User')) using ("role"::text check ("role" in ('Admin', 'SuperUser', 'User'))) - syntax error at or near "check"
```

I tried looking for a "check" in 12345_updatePermissions.js; however, I was not able to find it. The following is the contents of 12345_updatePermissions.js:

```
const tableName = 'User';

exports.up = async (knex) => {
  await knex.schema.alterTable(tableName, (table) => {
    table.dropColumn('role');
  });
  await knex.schema.alterTable(tableName, (table) => {
    table.enu('role', ['Owner', 'Admin', 'Researcher', 'AdvancedResearcher', 'User']).defaultTo('User');
  });
};

exports.down = async (knex) => {
  await knex.schema.alterTable(tableName, (table) => {
    table.enu('role', ['Admin', 'SuperUser', 'User']).defaultTo('User').alter();
  });
};
```

I've tried removing the `alter()` method at the end of the exports.down function, but to no avail (I really didn't think this would help, but I was desperate to try something). I don't know what else I should change to resolve this. I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me make sense of the error, especially the "check", and explain how I could go about fixing it.

Comment: I would strongly recommend you also ask the people who are _the absolute best suited to help you figure this out_, namely the knex developers over on https://github.com/knex/knex/issues - Stackoverflow might be convenient, but having the knex folks update either their code or docs to cover this situation will help not just you, but everyone using knex, which is where the value of open source really is. (and if they answer you there before someone does here, you can write an answer here as well and people can find the information in two places)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans. I just created an [issue](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/4575) in the Knex repository. I'll update my post here if I get an answer there before I do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my issue after playing around with the script for a bit. All I had to do was swap out `table.enu('role', ['Admin', 'SuperUser', 'User']).defaultTo('User').alter()` in favor of `table.dropColumn('role')` in line 14. The following is the contents of the updated 12345_updatePermissions.js:

```
const tableName = 'User';

exports.up = async (knex) => {
  await knex.schema.alterTable(tableName, (table) => {
    table.dropColumn('role');
  });
  await knex.schema.alterTable(tableName, (table) => {
    table.enu('role', ['Owner', 'Admin', 'Researcher', 'AdvancedResearcher', 'User']).defaultTo('User');
  });
};

exports.down = async (knex) => {
  await knex.schema.alterTable(tableName, (table) => {
    table.dropColumn('role');
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check how enums are created and what alter tries to do with it:

https://runkit.com/embed/88ztxi2dme5a

```
const Knex = require('knex');

const knex = Knex({
  client: 'pg',
});

knex.schema.table('table', table => {
  table.enu('role', ['Admin', 'SuperUser', 'User']).defaultTo('User');
}).toSQL().map(row => console.log(row.sql))

// CREATES: "alter table \"table\" add column \"role\" text check (\"role\" in ('Admin', 'SuperUser', 'User')) default 'User'"

knex.schema.alterTable('table', table => {
  table.enu('role', ['Admin', 'SuperUser', 'User']).defaultTo('User').alter();
}).toSQL().map(row => console.log(row.sql))

// CREATES: alter table "table" alter column "role" type text check ("role" in ('Admin', 'SuperUser', 'User')) using ("role"::text::text check ("role" in ('Admin', 'SuperUser', 'User')))
```

So from that one can see that .alter() doesn't support altering `enu` type of colums and to alter them one has to use raw queries, that drops old check constraint and then creates a new one with updated values.